# Type 'X' is not assignable to type MyType[keyof MyType]

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble with the following:

```
   interface MyType {
     [key: number]: number;
   }

   function myfunc<MyType>(map: MyType, key: keyof MyType) {
     map[key] = 4; // Error: type '4' is not assignable to type MyType[keyof MyType]
   }
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to make it safe to assign something to map[key]?

Comment: By syntax is looks like MyType[Index]. Like array of MyType. And you are trying to assign number to MyType.

Comment: @coreDeviOS I'm trying to assign a number value to the member of MyType.

Comment: FYI `MyType` could be redefined as `type MyType = Record<number, number>;`

Comment: yeah but by syntax it looks like array of MyType.

Comment: @coreDeviOS the interface `MyType` has an index signature declaring that `map[key]` is a number, arrays and dicts/maps use the same syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<MyType>` on `myfunc` introduces a template parameter that is different from `interface MyType`. Just get rid of it and it'll work.

```
function myfunc(map: MyType, key: keyof MyType) {
  map[key] = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you have (for unknown reasons) defined a generic type variable `MyType` which occludes your actual `MyType` declaration. This means that within the scope of the function, `MyType` refers to a generic type for which no further information can be inferred... hence the error.

It needs to change from

```
function myfunc<MyType>(map: MyType, key: keyof MyType){//...
```

to just

```
function myfunc(map: MyType, key: keyof MyType){//...
```